# pairwise substring a data frame and save them in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

```
# Example data
dat <- matrix(runif(2*300), ncol = 2, nrow = 20)
group <- rep_len(LETTERS[1:3], 20)
df <- cbind.data.frame(dat, Group = group)

# Greate subset groups
n <- levels(as.factor(group))
mylist <- combn(n, 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

I would like to subset my data according to pairwise combinations of the `group` attribute, and then save the result in `mylist`.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset` with `%in%` after looping over the `mylist`

```
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) subset(df, Group %in% x))
```

---

It can be also be done within `combn` by making use of `FUN` argument

```
combn(n, 2, FUN = function(x) subset(df, Group %in% x), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks a lot, @akrun.